# assiging pointer to pointer to char pointer such that allocation done in called function and parameter get freed in calling function C

Tags: c

I have a pointer to poinetr that I am getting in function as parameter `char **image`

now I want to assign it to char pointer such that if I allocate `disk` then the calling function of `test` can free it image and disk will be freed too. Is it possible in C? This is my function that calling function is calling and image is pointer to pointer parameter. I calling this function as `char *image="hello";test("hello",&image)`

```
int32_t test(const char *path,char **image){

*(char *)(&disk) =*image;
34       printf("ya %s\n",*disk);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need double pointers here at all. `image` and `disk` can point to the same allocated block of memory. `free`ing one would automatically free the other.

Comment: @babon Strictly speaking, you don't 'free a pointer'. You free a memory block pointed at by the pointer. When the block is freed, the pointer becomes invalid. And this applies to all _variables_ which store _the same pointer_, because it's the destination memory block which has been freed, not the pointer variable itself.

Comment: Yes I know basically I was allocating with malloc in some other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*(char *)(&disk)
          ^^^^^  take the address of disk (with type "pointer to type of disk")
 ^^^^^^^^^     ^ convert that to a pointer to char
^                and finally get the single char pointed to by that mess

*(char *)(&disk) = *image; // nope, you cannot assign a pointer to char to a char.
```

Comment: the problem is in calling function image is not string literal. its allocated with malloc, I was wrong I think when I shown the question code. I want what is written to image in calling function and print it in called function also if I making changes to image in called function then that changes should be seen in calling function. are u getting it

Comment: thanks for explanation. working now I mistaken did not see the code clearly working now